# opening csv file-random forest in R

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and trying to run a sample code of random forest from the tutorial: [Random Forest Using R: Step by Step Tutorial](http://dni-institute.in/blogs/random-forest-using-r-step-by-step-tutorial/).
For the very second line of the code:

```
names(termCrosssell)
```

I am getting the result as: 
    `age.job.marital.education.default.balance.housing.loan.contact.day.month.duration.campaign.pdays.previous.poutcome.y`

whereas, in the tutorial the format is different. I want to know if I have not correctly arranged the data file. Secondly, for

```
table(termCrosssell$y)/nrow(termCrosssell)
```

I am getting

```
# numeric(0)
```

I am unable to understand the result. I tried finding about the data file arrangement but could not get the answer.

Comment: It looks as if you have specified the wrong seperator in the csv file. Use `read.table` and make sure to set field seperator, decimal symbol, qoute, ... right. (Spaces and specila symbols get sustituted by dots in names, so it looks as if you have a `data.frame` with one column with all names concatenated to one long name.)

Comment: Yes, @snaut. read.table need to be done in the R code? As you said, in the data file one column with all names concatenated to one long name is there. Can you please explain the steps to be followed in detail. Thank you.

Comment: It seems @jls has posted the code in their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to address your problem without reproducible data. I followed the link, downloaded the dataset, but then had to open and re-name the .csv file. Indeed, the file uses ";" as separator. I got the correct results:

```
termcrosssell <- read.csv(file="crosssell.csv", header = T, sep = ";")
names(termcrosssell)
 [1] "age"       "job"       "marital"   "education" "default"   "balance"   "housing"  
 [8] "loan"      "contact"   "day"       "month"     "duration"  "campaign"  "pdays"    
[15] "previous"  "poutcome"  "y"
```

Comment: Thank you @jls. For the table(termCrosssell$y)/nrow(termCrosssell) command I am still getting the numeric(0). Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Again, I think your problems have to do with A. how you are reading in the data or B. the format of the original .csv file. When I ran `table(termCrosssell$y)/nrow(termCrosssell)` it returned: `no     yes 
0.88476 0.11524`

Comment: Thank you so much @jls. Your answers solved my question. Regards